# Is there a way to exclude large files or certain file types from an SVN update?

Tags: svn, version-control

Just wondering if its possible to exclude large files or certian file types from an SVN update?

I ask because I am doing a checkout from home, but we have got several large .flv files in trunk which I do not need at this time and I would like to save the bandwidth.

I am using Tortoise SVN.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Subversion 1.5 on your client and make use of [Sparse Checkouts](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html#sparse-checkouts). This will only work if you can ensure all of the large files are in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to move the .flv files out of trunk so that your updates stay simple.